# How to apply Redux to create click counter

Tags: react-redux

```js
// define initatial state
const initalState = {
  counter:0
};
// create reducer
const reducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ONE':
      return state + 1;
    case 'MINUS_ONE':
      return state - 1;
    default:
      return state
  }
};
// create action for incrementing
const IncrementAction = (newVal) => {
  return {
    type:"ADD_ONE",
  }
};

// create action for decrementing
const DecrementAction = () => {
  return {
    type:"MINUS_ONE"
  }
};

// create store
const store = createStore(reducer);
console.log(store.getState());

const action = (type) => {
  return (
      store.dispatch({type})
  )
};

function App(props) {
  console.log(props);
  const dispatch = props.dispatch;
  return (
      <div className="main">
        <p>result is:{props.counter} </p>
        <button onClick={IncrementAction(() => action('INCREMENT'))}>increment</button>
        <button>decrement</button>
      </div>
  );
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ counter: state.counter });
const Wrapper = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}><Wrapper/></Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

I want to create a click counter using Redux. I created a logic but it doesn't work. Above i try to change the state by clicking, but something goes wrong. What changes should i add to get the counter? I want to create functions for each button, and when i will click on a button to increment the counter and when i will click on another button to decremenet the value from state.

Comment: Can you post the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You should be incrementing or decrementing the counter in state. This is the first thing I notice that is wrong. Can you provide the error you get for a better understanding?

```
// define initatial state
const initalState = {
  counter:0
};
// create reducer
const reducer = (state = initalState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ONE':
      return state.counter + 1;
    case 'MINUS_ONE':
      return state.counter - 1;
    default:
      return state
  }
};
```

Comment: the erroris : `Uncaught Error: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.`

Comment: i changed to this `<button onClick={()=>{console.log(IncrementAction(() => action('INCREMENT')))}}>increment</button>`, but anyway it doesn't work, but the error was solved.